# Launches the audio player whenever trying to open any directory

Tags: 10.10, sound, directory

Am a new linux user and recently installed ubuntu 10.10 on my netbook.however it has this strange bug where whenever i click to open any directory instead it launches the default audio player-audacious.anyone experiencing the same and any suggestions on how i can fix?

Answer (score 1):

Been answered before ...happened to me to, here is answer
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9520970#post9520970